# Get length of a side of quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

An irregular quadrilateral  given 3 sides (A,B C) and 2 angles(a, b), how to calculate the length of D. As shown in [image: irregular quadrilateral]

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Welcome to mathematics.SE. If you don't include your own work/thoughts on the problem, it will quickly be closed for lack of context. Also you should read an introduction to MathJax/LaTeX and use that to make your post(s) here more readable.

Comment: Please improve your Question by adding some context.  The best approach to solving the underlying problem will depend on your background, and the little that you have written (a bare problem statement) gives no indication to Readers how well suited a response might be for you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the triangle with the sides $A$ and $D$. You can write the generalized Pythagoras's theorem to get the other side, let's call it $X$, in terms of $A$, $D$ (unknown), and $a$. You can also write the equation for the angle between $D$ and $X$, let's call it $x$. Then the angle between $X$ and $C$ is $b-x$. You can write the generalized Pythagoras's theorem for the triangle $CBX$. You now have three equations with three unknowns $X$, $x$, and $D$